# AlertView vs. AlertController in iOS7 and iOS8

Tags: ios, swift, compatibility, alerts

I've been reading that AlertController should be used for iOS 8 and up, while in iOS7 versions the AlertView is used.

Well I'm currently working on an app that I'd like to be compatible for iOS7 and up.  Do I have to either choose AlertView to only have iOS7 users use it and not 8, or choose AlertController and neglect everyone on iOS7 to not be able to use it?

I'd like to get both crowds, but it seems I can only use one and isolate a group of users.....is there a way to utilize both?

Answer (score 0):

You can use both. One for iOS 7 and one for iOS 8. Just do something like this:

```
if ([UIAlertController class]) }
  // iOS 8 - show alert controller
} else {
  // iOS 7 - show alert view
}
```

Comment: So this is the syntax that basically checks if the class is available?  I was unaware it would be that simple....unless we are on different pages.  I also saw this link about swift 2 (https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift2) and there is something mentioned about #available, that seems like it would also do the job!

Comment: It is that simple, and the result is the same as if you used #available in swift.